# array_unique() function in PHP does not work for my array

Tags: php, mysql

I have create a function for chat. I want to get only one value from set of values. I used array_unique function in it.

Error:

```
function get_chat_list($sender){
        global $conn;
        $sqlCode = "SELECT DISTINCT sender FROM chat WHERE connector LIKE '%$sender%' ";
        $sqlCode1 = "SELECT DISTINCT reciever FROM chat WHERE connector LIKE '$sender%'";
        var_dump($sqlCode1);
        $run = mysqli_query($conn,$sqlCode);
        $run1 = mysqli_query($conn,$sqlCode1);
        var_dump($run1);
        $recievers = array();
        while($reciever = mysqli_fetch_assoc($run)){
            if($reciever['sender'] == $sender){

            }else{
                $recievers[] = array('reciever'=>$reciever['sender']);
            }

        }

        while($reciever = mysqli_fetch_assoc($run1)){
            if($reciever['reciever'] == $sender){

            }else{
                $recievers[] = array('reciever'=>$reciever['reciever']);
            }

        }

        return array_unique($recievers);
    }
```

[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WZYvV.png)

Comment: Don't use image links. Type (or copy) the errors into the question.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to make string comparisons on arrays (non-scalar).  I don't think array_unique works on an array of arrays, it has to be array of strings.  If you want unique receivers, you're going to need to turn that value into a string.

I don't know what you might be using the array for, but one solution would be to serialize/stringify the array and then you can run your unique, then unwrap/desalinize the string later.  I'm not sure why if there is only one value in that array, you are using a key for it.  How about just storing the string and it should work for you

EX:

```
function get_chat_list($sender){
      global $conn;
      $sqlCode = "SELECT DISTINCT sender FROM chat WHERE connector LIKE '%$sender%' ";
      $sqlCode1 = "SELECT DISTINCT reciever FROM chat WHERE connector LIKE '$sender%'";
      var_dump($sqlCode1);
      $run = mysqli_query($conn,$sqlCode);
      $run1 = mysqli_query($conn,$sqlCode1);
      var_dump($run1);
      $recievers = array();
      while($reciever = mysqli_fetch_assoc($run)){
          if($reciever['sender'] != $sender){
              $recievers[] = $reciever['sender'];
          }

      }

      while($reciever = mysqli_fetch_assoc($run1)){
          if($reciever['reciever'] != $sender){
            $recievers[] = $reciever['reciever'];
          }

      }

      return array_unique($recievers);
   }
```